# Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, override-model, magento2.4.5p1

I have Magento enterprise version 2.4.5-p1, I am getting following error in the system.log

> Error:- .CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class
> Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121

I thought the issue is in this constructor parameter code which I have overridden from default Magento RMA's Model,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    AttributeValueFactory $customAttrFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Rma\Model\RmaFactory $rmaFactory,
    \Magento\Rma\Model\Config $rmaConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTimeDateTime,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Rma\Helper\Data $rmaHelper,
    TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    RmaRepositoryInterface $rmaRepoInterface,
    RmaAttributesManagementInterface $metadataService,
    AddressRenderer $addressRenderer,
    RmaEntityFactory $customReturn,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $extensionFactory,
        $customAttrFactory,
        $storeManager,
        $rmaFactory,
        $rmaConfig,
        $transportBuilder,
        $dateTimeDateTime,
        $inlineTranslation,
        $rmaHelper,
        $localeDate,
        $rmaRepoInterface,
        $metadataService,
        $addressRenderer,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->rmaConfig = $rmaConfig;
    $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->rmaHelper = $rmaHelper;
    $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
    $this->customReturn = $customReturn;
}
```

Can anyone have idea, where am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: run this command and check it resolved or not ?    
                                                    
rm -rf generated/*  var/cache var/page_cache

Comment: Also Need to check all variables passed of the parent class in the construct or not

Comment: @CharmiPatel, appreciate your response, I already passed all the parents class parameters in constructor, and also tried running deploy command and tried removing generated and var folder

Comment: please replace with the whole file here